# How to Re-enable a disabled android package while in recovery/Fastboot?

Tags: android, adb, android-11

I am using Realme X7 5g (RMX3092). I used ADB to remove all the bloatware in the phone.
I did not remove the launcher / keyboard or any important apps.
Now the Phone is stuck at the login screen.
[Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x5Qk_QJoEXWPznlfIxLh0s1DVntsWn-w/view?usp=drivesdk)
Is there any way to re-enable the disabled packages while in Recovery or Fast boot mode ?

I tried using both and get the error [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdFuN.png)

I have one of the old update packages in the memory of the phone but the system is not allowing to degrade to a older version. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpJGR.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.